# Why does setting the value of an array element cause my script to fail?

Tags: javascript, html

This simple bit of JavaScript worked fine until I added the line

```
bigImgExists[figNum - 1] = true; <!-- this line causes problem -->
```

It’s obviously causing some sort of run time error, but I can’t understand why. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_const.asp  shows an example of setting an array element in this way. Here’s the full script:

```js
"use strict";
const bigImgExists = new array(18).fill(false);
function showBigImg(figNum) {
    var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
    tempDiv.setAttribute("id", "bigImg1");
    tempDiv.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    const figcap = document.getElementById('figcap1');
    figcap.appendChild (tempDiv);
    tempDiv.innerHTML = "I created this";
    bigImgExists[figNum - 1] = true; <!-- this line causes problem -->

document.getElementById('thumb' + figNum).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('bigImg' + figNum).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: It fails much earlier, at `new array(18)`

Comment: (This is associated with [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420506/you-can-t-post-new-questions-right-now#comment927884_420506)—likely to be automatically deleted and then only visible for users with more than 10,000 reputation points.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably this figNum variable is coming as a string. Add a plus sign and try it.

```
bigImgExists[+figNum - 1] = true
```

Comment: This probably is not the problem. Javascript casts substractions to numbers automatically. So >"2" + 1 = "21" but >"2" - 1 = 1; so the -1 would already make the conversion, unless the string is empty, something which the + would not solve either

Answer (score 0):

```
const bigImgExists = new array(18).fill(false);
```

Should be

```
const bigImgExists = new Array(18).fill(false);
```

The [`Array()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) constructor needs to be capitalized.